# How to make user register but not login in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, login, plugin, register, user

I want to make user register and redirect to login page in Magento 2.4.
User not automatic login.

I have created a plugin for that and created a file ( app/code/Registration/Redirect/Plugin/Customer/Account/CreatePost.php )

```
<?php

namespace Registration\Redirect\Plugin\Customer\Account;

class CreatePost
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $url;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
)
{
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject,
    $resultRedirect
) {
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
    return $resultRedirect;
}
}
```

How to make it not loggedin automatic only just register and redirect on login page.
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: I think you need to use before OR around plugin to modify actual execute.Now you are using after plugin and customer is already register and login.

Comment: @Pawan will you please tell me how to do that i have see need to do some with $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer); line but how to do that will you please help.

Comment: YES, you need to remove code `$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);`.just copy whole function code and `return` after customer account create code i.e after dispatch `customer_register_success` event.

Comment: Did you checked my answer? Is it worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code in your plugin

```
<?php

namespace Registration\Redirect\Plugin\Customer\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class CreatePost
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Connect constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirectInterface
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
        RedirectInterface $redirectInterface,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
        $this->redirect = $redirectInterface;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function afterExecute(CreatePost $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($this->customerSession->getRegisterSuccess()){
            $lastCustomerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
            $this->customerSession->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl())
                ->setLastCustomerId($lastCustomerId);

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
            $result = $resultRedirect;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have also done the same.